# Why can't the compiler see IEnumerable<T> when IReadonlyDictionary<U, T> is also present

Tags: c#, interface

I have a class in .NET Framework 4.8 that implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IReadonlyDictionary<U, T>`:

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<Bar>, IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Bar>
{
    public Bar this[int key] => /* ... */;

    public IEnumerable<int> Keys => /* ... */;

    public IEnumerable<Bar> Values => /* ... */;

    public int Count => /* ... */;

    public bool ContainsKey(int key) => /* ... */;

    public IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator() => /* ... */;

    public bool TryGetValue(int key, out Bar value) => /* ... */;

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { /* ... */; }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, Bar>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Bar>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        /* ... */;
    }
}
```

Using this class in a `foreach` loop works fine:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foreach (var bar in foo)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

But if I try to use an extention method for `IEnumerable<T>`, for example

```
bool b = foo.Any();
```

I'm getting the error

> CS1061    'Foo' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no accessible extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'Foo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code already contains `using System.Linq`, and If I remove `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Bar>` from my class the error goes away. Why can't the compiler see `IEnumerable<T>` when `IReadonlyDictionary<U, T>` is also present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`IReadOnlyDictionary<K, V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2?view=net-8.0) inherits from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>`. Your class implements both `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Bar>>` and `IEnumerable<Bar>`.

The extension method [`IEnumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-8.0) is generic, and is an extension on all `IEnumerable<T>`s.

```
public static bool Any<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

The compiler cannot figure out what `TSource` should be - whether it should be `Bar` or `KeyValuePair<int, Bar>`.

`foreach` doesn't have this issue only because you implemented `IEnumerable<Bar>` *implicitly*. This allows `GetEnumerator` to be found directly on `Foo` when the compiler does a member lookup. If you had implemented it explicitly like this:

```
IEnumerator<Bar> IEnumerable<Bar>.GetEnumerator() => ...;
```

`foreach` wouldn't be able to figure out what you want either. Follow the [steps that the compiler takes, specified in the language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1295-the-foreach-statement) to see exactly how this works.

In addition to casting it to the desired instantiation of `IEnumerable<T>` like in CodeCaster's answer, you can also tell it what `TSource` you want by specifying the type arguments of `Any`:

```
bool b = foo.Any<Bar>();
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't know whether you want to call `Any()` on:

- `IEnumerable<Bar>`, or
- `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Bar> : IEnumerable<<KeyValuePair<int, Bar>>`

So be explicit:

```
IEnumerable<Bar> foo = ...
// or
IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Bar> foo = ...

if (foo.Any())
{
    // ...
}
```

But yeah, the compiler error looks confusing, it could be clearer about that ambiguity.

Comment: You can also inline that `if (((IEnumerable<Bar>) foo).Any())`